# Where can I find the graphics for patent CA2311951C?

Tags: claims, ca2311951c

In reference to the patent: [CA2311951C](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2311951C) “Ice skate blade”

I cannot see an image and cannot follow the claims without an image. Where can I find the referenced image(s)?

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, the 'External Links' at the bottom of the 'Bibliographic box' of Google Patents directs to individual patent authorities that provide the complete document with images.

For example, the specification, images and correspondence for this Canadian patent are available from [CIPO](http://brevets-patents.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/patent/2311951/summary.html) (the Canadian patent authority).

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figures 2A and 2B]